# Why does my SIR differential equation solver not work?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of SIR differential equations with Mathematica.

My code is:

```
DSolve[
  {S'[t] == -0.0005 S[t] i[t], 
   i'[t] == 0.0005*S[t] i[t] - 0.1 i[t], 
   R'[t] == 0.1 i[t], 
   S[0] == 1500, i[0] == 1, R[0] == 0}, 
  {S[t], i[t], R[t]}, t]
```

However, when I evaluate the above, the solver goes on and on forever. 
Investigating I found this code on another question on Math Stack exchange:

```
b = 0.18; k = 0.14;
system = 
  {s'[t] == -b s[t] i[t], 
   i'[t] == b s[t] i[t] - k i[t], 
   r'[t] == k i[t], 
   s[0] == 1, i[0] == .007, r[0] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[system, {s, i, r}, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], i[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 100}]
`
```

Can somebody explain why this code runs and my code takes forever?

Comment: `DSolve[]` tries to look for a *symbolic* solution, which takes more effort that a numerical integration like what is done by `NDSolve[]`. Do you really need a symbolic solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is likely no analytic solution. I recommend using `NDSolveValue`. It will provide interpolation functions that are good approximations almost instantly. You would code it like this:

```
{sF, iF, rF} =
  NDSolveValue[
    {S'[t] == -0.0005 S[t] i[t], i'[t] == 0.0005*S[t] i[t] - 0.1 i[t], R'[t] == 0.1 i[t], 
     S[0] == 1500, i[0] == 1, R[0] == 0},
    {S, i, R}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

And you plot the results like this:

```
Plot[{sF[t], iF[t], rF[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotLegends -> {S, "I", R}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the help!